# Azure storage query does not return data if partition key contains an exclamation mark

Tags: c#, .net, azure, encoding, azure-storage

I stored some data where the partition key contains an exclamation mark and when I do a query on that partition key I get weird results.

I have tried the following. Lets say the partitionkey is t!est

I have tried the following queries with their respectful results

```
PartitionKey eq 't!est' = Noting returned
PartitionKey gt 't!est' = Noting returned
PartitionKey ge 't!est' = Noting returned
PartitionKey lt 't!est' = Record returned (Along side others)
PartitionKey le 't!est' = Record returned (Along side others)
```

I would have expected that the equals would have at least retrieved my record. Is there something I am not understanding?

Tested with:

- SDK .Net Version 7.2.1
- SDK .Net Version 9.3.3
- Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer Version 1.8.1

Comment: You are sure it is the exclamation mark and not something that looks like it but has a different unicode code point? Not sure such a symbol exists though. Do you have any way of retrieving the partition keys in use to check what's actually in there?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes i did retrieve it manually and I am most certainly sure that it is an exclamation mark, I have even tested with dummy data and entered the exclamation mark myself and still the same result

Comment: Very interesting observation. I am able to reproduce this issue. This is what I noticed. When I specify a query like `PartitionKey eq 'te!st'` I don't get any result back. However when I specify an invalid query like `PartitionKey neq 'te!st'`, I obviously get an error message back. The interesting thing is that in my query, `!` gets changed to `not` so the query that was actually sent to storage is `PartitionKey eq 'tenottest'`. I tried it with Node SDK. Let me try it with .Net SDK as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have tried it from both the .Net SDK and the azure storage explorer and both of them have the same behaviour as you described. Thanks a lot for shedding some light into this.

Comment: For some reason I am not able to reproduce this issue with .Net SDK. Can you edit your question and include more details like SDK version, your code etc. I can understand about Storage Explorer as it makes use of Node SDK and that has an issue. I have opened an issue on GitHub for Node SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/588.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have included the version I tested with, as for code I have used the above filters and always reproduced it. I have also filed an issue on GitHub for .Net SDK https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [GauravMantri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235303/azure-storage-query-does-not-return-data-if-partition-key-contains-an-exclamatio#comment99091644_56235303) in his comment. This is an issue with the sdk where it is converting the '!' to a 'not', hence query will not match.